# hash.indexOf() if else statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have several buttons (3) that appear when there is a certain hashtag in the url. The problem is that when I use `if, else if` statements the codes don't quite play their part. When the hash tag is `iphone` three buttons appear and attaches the correct strings but when I click `windowsphone` three buttons appear but they somehow take me back to the `iphone` strings.

I've tried `else`, `else if`, and all `if`'s but nothing works. `windowsphone`, basically, isn't loading it's strings in the HTML Markup.

iphone buttons (with hashtag in url): http://jsfiddle.net/66kCf/show/#iphone

windowsphone buttons (with hashtag in url): http://jsfiddle.net/66kCf/show/#windowsphone

Origninal JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/66kCf/

```
if (hash.indexOf('iphone') != -1)
{
    $("#linkdiv").append(nextLink);
    $("#linkdiv1").append(nextLink);
    $("#linkdiv2").append(nextLink);
}   
else if (hash.indexOf('windowsphone') != -1)
{
    $("#linkdiv3").append(nextLink);
    $("#linkdiv4").append(nextLink);
    $("#linkdiv5").append(nextLink);
}
```

Comment: `console.log(window.location.hash);`

Comment: @zerkms will that solve my problem with the if statements?

Comment: @zerkms I've never used that tag. Should I just cut and paste exactly how it is?

Comment: see https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console

Comment: also https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only problem I can see is you are not closing the `plain` element properly, don't use self closing tag which is creating a nested dom structure where the windows plain element is nested inside an iphone element.

```
<plain id='linkdiv' href='phone-condition' onclick="location.href = $(this).attr('href')+'?/phone-shipping-method?q1=AppleiPhone&x=103&y=13-ship-it-yourself/#iPhone';return false" ></plain>
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/sHrV3/show/#windowsphone)

Use your browser developer tool to inspect the generated html you can see how the markup is wrongly nested where one `plain` element is nested inside another one

So instead of `<plain ..... />` use `<plain ....></plain>`